# capturing https traffic from a JAVA app server

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am writing a java app server that connects to another third party server over HTTPS. I would like to capture the traffic between these two servers (which is over HTTPS). The third party server's private key is not accessible to us. They have provided us pfx file which our server is using while making a connection to that thrird party server. Any tool I can use? I have seen several posts regarding this, but not sure which way works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of SSL is that you cannot do this... Check [Diffie Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchangehttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) on why, even if you have the keys, you will not be able to decrypt traffic.